# Finding the distance to the next higher value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame containing floating point values

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,1,4,3,2,5,4,7])
```

I'm trying to find for each number, when (how many indices need to move **forward**) till I find the next number larger than the current number, if there is no larger number, I mark it with some value (like 999999).

So for the example above, the correct answer should be

```
result = [1,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,999999]
```

Currently I've solved it by very slow double loop with `itertuples` (meaning O(n^2))

Is there a smarter way to do it ?

Comment: Any reason in particular why you’re using a pandas DataFrame? Is this just an example, and your real DataFrame is different?

Comment: My real data frame is a huge time series containing temperatures and many other parameters measured by some sensor over time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a numpy based one leveraging broadcasting:

```
a = my_df.squeeze().to_numpy() # my_df.squeeze().values for versions 0.24.0.<

diff_mat = a - a[:,None]
result = (np.triu(diff_mat)>0).argmax(1) - np.arange(diff_mat.shape[1])
result[result <= 0] = 99999
```

---

```
print(result)

array([    1,     2,     1,     3,     2,     1,     2,     1, 99999],
      dtype=int64)
```

---

Where `diff_mat` is the distance matrix, and we're looking for the values from the main diagonal onwards, which are greater than `0`:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  3,  2,  1,  4,  3,  6],
       [-1,  0, -1,  2,  1,  0,  3,  2,  5],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  3,  2,  1,  4,  3,  6],
       [-3, -2, -3,  0, -1, -2,  1,  0,  3],
       [-2, -1, -2,  1,  0, -1,  2,  1,  4],
       [-1,  0, -1,  2,  1,  0,  3,  2,  5],
       [-4, -3, -4, -1, -2, -3,  0, -1,  2],
       [-3, -2, -3,  0, -1, -2,  1,  0,  3],
       [-6, -5, -6, -3, -4, -5, -2, -3,  0]], dtype=int64)
```

We have `np.triu` for that:

```
np.triu(diff_mat)

array([[ 0,  1,  0,  3,  2,  1,  4,  3,  6],
       [ 0,  0, -1,  2,  1,  0,  3,  2,  5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  3,  2,  1,  4,  3,  6],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -2,  1,  0,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  2,  1,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3,  2,  5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int64)
```

And by checking which are greater than `0`, and taking the `argmax` of the boolean `ndarray` we'll find the first value greater than `0` in each row:

```
(np.triu(diff_mat)>0).argmax(1)
array([1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 0], dtype=int64)
```

We only need to subtract the corresponding offset from the main diagonal to the beginning

Comment: Added some explanations @OopsUser

Comment: How does it compare in terms of performance @OopsUser good enough?

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(ss:pd.Series):
    return ss.loc[ss.gt(ss.tail(1).squeeze())].index.min()-ss.tail(1).index.min()

my_df.squeeze()[::-1].expanding().apply(function1)[::-1].fillna(999999)

：

[1,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,999999]
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**